# Is it possible to check if a word is really an english word via regex?

Tags: regex, nlp

When I say english I really mean vs gobbledy gook. I'm not trying to filter out maitre'd or espanol or whatever.

So basically I'm trying to test whether a word is made of entirely of pronounceable syllables.

So here would be a regex:

```
if re.match(r'^([^aeiouy]{1,3}[aeiouy]{1,3}[^aeiouy]{1,3}|[aeiouy]{1,3}[^aeiouy]{1,3})+
    print "gobbledy gook!!!"
```

What its checking for: C=consonant V=vowel

CVC or VC groups of characters. groups are 1-3 characters in length

Does this make sense?,the_word) is None:
*xCodexBlockxPlacexHolderx*

What its checking for: C=consonant V=vowel

CVC or VC groups of characters. groups are 1-3 characters in length

Does this make sense?

Comment: Given the massive variation and complexity of the English language, especially the number of loan words I would suggest that this is not going to be an effective approach.

Comment: You're on a hiding to nothing with this. Your pattern happily matches `gobbldrygook`, for example.

Comment: What you're asking is, in fact, so complex and error prone that I think it would be more effective to just use a spellcheck algorithm.  Yours, for example, says "don't" isn't a word.  It also says "76ers", a proper noun, isn't a word.  Also "crwth", one of several words borrowed from Welsh.  Oh, and all sorts of initializations like "TCP/IP".  Another alternative is to use a real [phonetic algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonetic_algorithm), which I suspect is much closer to what you're asking for.

Comment: I think the only way to do it is create a regex with all the english words like "word1|word2|word3|..."  :p

Comment: What are you trying to exclude?  Obviously foreign language words like "frömjöl" or "hakkapeliitta"?  Or random line noise like "asdasedasdf" or "~~%~)%#NO CARRIER"?

Answer (score 5):

Yes and no. It is, in a certain sense, possible; the comments give the trivial (and horribly verbose and sluggish) way to do so. But as to whether it is in any sense useful to abuse regexen for this task? **No**. There's simply far too much variation between valid words, and even the weakened verification you're doing that makes no attempt to handle plausible-but-wrong words like 'rong' will require absolutely impractical customization to do the job.

This sort of problem is why [JWZ (Jamie Zawinski) said](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski#Attributed):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.